# Add and reference new face in Emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs-faces

I defined a new face in Emacs, but the coloring does not take effect. Here is the face and mode definition in `~/.emacs`:

```
(defface sml-highlight-operator-face
  '((t (:foreground "red")))
  "SML operator highlighting"
  :group 'basic-faces)

(defvar sml-font-lock-keywords
   ((,(regexp-opt '("fun" "fn" "let" "val" "datatype" "type" "case" "of" "end" "structure" "struct" "signature" "sig"))
     (0 font-lock-keyword-face))
    ("[][=|><-+;,{}():]" (0 sml-highlight-operator-face))))

;;;###autoload
(define-derived-mode sml-mode prog-mode "SML"
  "SML major mode."
  (set (make-local-variable 'comment-start) "(* ")
  (set (make-local-variable 'comment-end) " *)")
  (set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-defaults)
       '(sml-font-lock-keywords)))
```

However, when I use `font-lock-builtin-face` instead of `sml-highlight-operator-face` those characters are highlighted (albeit with a color I don't want). What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The element `(0 sml-highlight-operator-face)` in your font-lock-keywords does not say "use face sml-highlight-operator-face for sub-match 0" but "use the result of evaluating the expression `sml-highlight-operator-face` as the face to put on sub-match 0".

IOW, you need to use `(0 'sml-highlight-operator-face)`.

BTW, the convention nowadays is to not use a `-face` suffix for faces (tho such a suffix is still used of course for *variables* holding faces), tho we haven't bothered to rename the `font-lock-foo-face` faces to `font-lock-foo` yet (even though it would very much help the confusion you're seeing where a lot of font-lock rules say things like `(0 font-lock-foo-face)` and people think it refers to the `font-lock-foo-face` face whereas it refers to the `font-lock-foo-face` variable (whose value holds the `font-lock-foo-face` face).

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you very much, Stefan!